# clean up hard drive Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, terminal, hard-drive, ubuntu-12.04

Hi i am wondering how do I clean up and remove old files that are taking up space? In Ubuntu 12.04.

I have only ssh interface (terminal interface).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/cleaning-up-all-unnecessary-junk-files-in-ubuntu.html
Look at: Remove partial packages, Remove unnecessary locale data, Remove "orphaned" packages.

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install localepurge
sudo apt-get install deborphan
sudo deborphan | xargs sudo apt-get -y remove --purge
```

Answer (score 1):

`du`

or

`find / -size +1024000`

....